# Opening of a xml document in internet explore

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I open the xml document in internet explore in c sharp dot net with winforms only

Comment: Do you mean that you have an xml document in internet explorer that you want to read, or that you have an xml document that you want to open into IE?

Comment: Yes sir, I want to open the xml document which is i have stored in string variable want to open in IE through c# code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works perfectly.

```
string strFileName = @"C:\File.xml";
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = strFileName;
proc.Start();
```